# Updating panel content when MenuItem is clicked

Tags: javascript, gwt, onclick, menuitem

The situation is that I have a MenuBar with MenuItems. Those MenuItems all have commands. These are organizer commands. They are intended to organize the content of a panel when the command is clicked. Here is an example of one of them:

```
public class OrganizeByCategory implements Command{
    private RuleListPanel theRulesList;


    public OrganizeByCategory(RuleListPanel rlp)
    {
        theRulesList = rlp;
    }
    @Override
public void execute() {
        theRulesList.organizedDrools.clear();
    theRulesList.populateByCategory();
}

}
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that, when this command is executed, the panel content is not updated. The clear command executes properly, because the content immediately vanishes. If I enter debug mode I can step through the code in populateByCategory(). Every line fires, everything does what I expect, and all objects end up with their appropriate values. The panel does not update in the browser, however. I'm pretty confident the method itself works because it is fired when the panel loads for the first time and works then.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Should I be using an onClick listener instead somehow? If so, why can't one pass an onClick listener through the MenuItem constructor like a Command?

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having here was due to a naive understanding of panels. My populate methods were instantiating a whole new panel every time, then linking them by reference to the class field which stores them. Turns out that this doesn't work. One needs to keep the original instance of an object. In the case of panels, you should use panel.clear() in order to reset the panel to a clean state. All my methods which were starting with instantiation of a new panel now start with a clear and I simply instantiate the panel once in a constructor.